# How do I import the nth sheet from an excel workbook with doCmd.transferSpreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, import

I want to import data from the n<sup>th</sup> worksheet of an Excel workbook with `doCmd.transferSpreadsheet`. This command requires the *sheet's name* as 6<sup>th</sup> Parameter. Unfortunately, the name of the sheet keeps chaning (think `last edited by XYZ, March 29`) so that I have no chance of knowing the name of the sheet I am interested in.

Is there a way to indicate the range by sheet position rather than sheet name?

Comment: If you know the index of the sheet, you can use Sheets(index).Name to get the name of the sheet or Sheets(index) to directly refer to the sheet

Comment: @gizlmeier I am afraid but that doesn't work. It seems to try to find a sheet by the litereal name of `sheets(index)`

Comment: obviously you have to replace index with a number, i just wrote index to make it clear where to put it 1 for example is the first sheet

Comment: Yes, I did replace `index` with the corresponding number.

Comment: Weird. It should defenitely work like this Sheets(1).Name

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you don't know the index, only the position (not equivalent, sorry), you need to look at each sheet in the workbook. Something like this:

```
SheetNameBaseString="whatever you know from the sheet name that won't change"
for each sheetVariable in workbookObject.Sheets
if instr(sheetVariable, SheetNameBaseString)<>0 _ 
then theSheetThatIWant=sheetVariable.index
next sheetVariable
docmd.transferspreadsheet ......., sheets(theSheetThatIWant) ........
```

Now, if you have multiple sheets that have the same 'base' name... you have a problem on your hands. :) Then again, if you have your users create new sheets, then the most recently created sheet ought to be the one you want. And that sheet's index, under many circumstances, may be equivalent to the highest sheet index in your workbook. So just put this if statement inside the one above, and say `if sheetvariable.index>theSheetThatIWant then theSheetThatIWant=sheetVariable.index`.

Another option here might be to `format(instrrev(sheetVariable.name,",")) inside your loop and grab the newest, IF the format you gave above is 100% accurate, and IF you know that the sheet you are looking for is always the one renamed most recently and IF it always has the correct data in the format you are looking for.

But, at the end of the day, if you have no control over the naming conventions of your users, or the workbook has so many uses that you can't predict what the users will be doing and in what order, you may need to rethink the entire workbook. You know, it isn't just Access isn't the only Office project that can be 'split'... you may have to separate your front end from your data, and change the name of the worksheet/table/data yourself. Not ideal if you are inheriting someone's tool, but it may be better than continually guessing sheet 'position' and getting it wrong... and looking stupid to the customer in the process.

Comment: I assume that this was downvoted because someone is denying the possible existence of hidden worksheets and chart sheets. I say, if you have control over your environment enough to know that those things will never exist, then you can and should take control of the naming conventions of your users. Use a button, for goodness' sakes! :)